# Displaying all files under path

Tags: php

I am using the glob function as such;

```
<?php
    $files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");
    for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $imagePath = $files[$i];
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imagePath);
        $imageName = str_replace("img/", "", $withoutExt);
        print $imagePath."<br />";
        print $imageName."<br />";
        echo '<img src="'.$imagePath .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
    }
?>
```

Which is on my sub-domain and I know works as previously it was simply glob("img/*.*") which displayed all the files.

On the same page files are uploaded to "../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/" however setting glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*") does not display my files.

Comment: PHP is a server-side, so you need to be in your server's dir. Desktop is out of the local server.

Comment: Have you already tried using the absolute path to that folder?

Comment: I upload files to this path using my PHP code. This is indeed the correct path. root > Admin > index.php is where this script is and it needs to request to see files under root > desktop > IMG > BananzaNews > Thumbs.

Comment: `define("UPLOAD_DIR", "../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/");` works completely find on my admin/index page to upload to this file location.

Comment: Just discovered that `$files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");` whereas `$files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/*.*");` will work...

Comment: Maybe this does not work as there is just one file at the moment? `for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)`

Comment: Bingo! I need to set $i to equal 0...